# module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'FileWriter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

Why is tensor flow throwing me this exception " module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'FileWriter'" each time i try to run my MCP Neuron, How can i go about solving the issue at hand ? I have search on stack but couldn't find any solution that fit my problem. can anyone help me out.

```
# McCulloch Pitt Neuron built with Tensorflow and represented with
# Tensorboard


import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

PATH = os.getcwd()

LOG_DIR = PATH+ '/output/'
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()


# 1.Configuration to optimize CPU performance by defining
#   thread pools. For this example 4 is enough. A variable
#   replace the constant
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=4,
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=4
)

# 2.Defining the x values, their w weights,the b bias,y weight calculation
#   and the s sigmoid activation function

x = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 5), name='x')
w = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5, 1), name='w')
b = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1), name='b')
y = tf.matmul(x, w) + b
s = tf.nn.sigmoid(y)


# 3.Starting a session providing constants as weight inputs
#   The Perceptron,a neuron that can learn its weights, will provide  with our present day
#   automatic weight calculations
with tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config) as tfs:
    tfs.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    
    w_t = [[.1, .7, .75, .60, .20]]
    x_1 = [[10, 2, 1., 6., 2.]]
    b_1 = [1]
    w_1 = np.transpose(w_t)
    
    value = tfs.run(s, 
        feed_dict={
            x: x_1, 
            w: w_1,
            b: b_1
        }
    )
    
print ('value for threshold calculation',value)
print ('Availability of lx',1-value)
         
  
#___________Tensorboard________________________

#with tf.Session() as sess:

Writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR, tfs.graph)
Writer.close()


def launchTensorBoard():
    import os
    os.system('tensorboard --logdir='+LOG_DIR)
    return

import threading
t = threading.Thread(target=launchTensorBoard, args=([]))
t.start()

tfs.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using either:

```py
Writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(LOG_DIR)
```

Or this if you want to also pass a graph:

```py
Writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR, tfs.graph)
```

See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/summary/FileWriter) for more information.